# Restricting privileges for anonymous authentication in Firebase with Angular

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am struggling with security rules in Firebase for anonymously authenticated users. I want users to be able to create, read, update, and delete their own projects using anonymous authentication. When I use the code below, Firebase denies permission to the database: `Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

Does my Angular code need to first create a users folder of some sort in Firebase even though I'm using anonymous authentication?

[EDIT: I've included my routes and some additional code in case it helps.]

Javascript:

```
myApp.factory('fbAuth', function($firebaseAuth, $firebase) {
var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com');
var authData = ref.getAuth();

    if (authData) {console.log('Authenticated user with uid:', authData.uid); } else {
    ref.authAnonymously(function (error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Login Failed!', error);
            } else {
                console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
            }
        });
    }
     return authData;
    });

myApp.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL+'/projects')).$asArray();
});

myApp.factory('Selections', function($firebase, fbURL) {
return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL+'/services')).$asArray();
});

myApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function ProjectListCtrl(Projects) {
var projectList = this;
projectList.projects = Projects;

projectList.total = function(){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(projectList.projects, function(project) {
        total += project.type.cost;

    });
    return total;
};

});
myApp.controller('SelectionListCtrl', function (Selections) {
var selectionList = this;
selectionList.selections = Selections;
this.selectedServices = Selections;


});
```

Routes:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('selection', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'list': {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
                controller: 'ProjectListCtrl as projectList',
            }
        },
        'selectionlist': {
            templateUrl: 'views/selectionlist.html',
            controller: 'SelectionListCtrl as selectionList',
        }
    })
```

Security Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
  "projects": {
    "$project_id" : {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !=null && auth.uid === $uid" }
  }
 },  
  "$other": {".validate": false }
 }
}
```

Firebase Data Structure

```
Root
  - projects
     + -JiVDL4RUSladYTqqHl6
     + -JiVIdH8QIQ8o8q3iKvf
     + -JiYY44i6AOGzTjPDNVM
```

Comment: Hi Ken! Where is `Projects` being utilized? This seems like a crucial detail for recognizing why you see these errors. (hint: it's probably called before authAnonymously() completes.) Your security rules look fine, although auth != null is superfluous in this case, but fine if it helps readability.

Comment: @Kato Thanks for the hint. You're right, projects is being utilized on the initial page. Should I be using `resolve` in the router to fix this?

Comment: Resolve would certainly help; it's hard to tell without knowing exactly how it all fits together. You might also be able to invoke something or broadcast an event from the authAnonymously() callback. But I'd [pick resolve myself](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) if given the choice as it's [more elegant](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/routes.js#L33)

Comment: @Kato Thank you again. I added some additional code to give a better sense of how it all fits together (or how it's not fitting together). I'd like to try your more elegant solution. Is the simpleLogin still the right option here? I wasn't sure how it fits in in with the updated Firebase changes described in this [post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-10-03-major-updates-to-firebase-user-auth.html).

Comment: $Kato I really want to use Firebase with my project, but I'm having an impossible time with this anonymous authentication and the associated rules. I've used resolve according to the link you provided, but now nothing loads. Any suggestions?